# get related column data in array in mysql + pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables, related between groups.id and users.group:

```
users:

+-- id --+------ email --------+ group +
|   1    | admin@email.com     |  2    |
+--------+---------------------+-------+
|   2    | user@email.com      |  1    |
+--------+---------------------+-------+

groups:

+-- id --+------ name- --------+
|   1    | user                |
+--------+---------------------+
|   2    | admin               |
+--------+---------------------+
```

When i use a regular select:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare(SELECT * FROM users);
$sth->execute();
var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

I got something like this:

```
 0 => 
 array (size=7)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'email' => string 'admin@email.com' (length=15)
  'group' => string '2' (length=1)

 1 => array (size=7)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'email' => string 'user@email.com' (length=14)
  'group' => string '1' (length=1)
```

My question is, how i can get an array inside "group" with a data from related table directly with mysql statement? 
Something like this:

```
 0 => 
 array (size=3)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'email' => string 'admin@email.com' (length=15)
  'group' => array(size=2)
     'id'  => string '2' (length=1)
     'name' => string 'admin' (length=5)


 1 => array (size=3)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'email' => string 'user@email.com' (length=14)
  'group' => array(size=2)
     'id'  => string '1' (length=1)
     'name' => string 'user' (length=4)
```

Comment: @jsalonen but, with left join i got group table at same lvl in array, not inside a "group" key

Comment: Mysql will always return flat rows, so it is not possible to get your multi level array directly with mysql statement. You will have to create your subarray in php. The closest you can do is to concat_ws() all your group related info from a join in mysql and explode every row in php.

Comment: @piotrm Well, that was what I imagined, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine any benefit in creating the additional depth in your output structure.

Just use a JOIN only select the columns that you actually need.  If you aren't going to use the `groups.id` value, then don't add it to the select.

Ultimately just package your data in flat rows and get on with whatever processing you need to do.

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT users.id, users.email, groups.name
                      FROM users
                      JOIN groups ON users.group = groups.id");
$sth->execute();
var_export($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```